# Do we have a inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{\arctan s}$

Tags: integration, asymptotics, laplace-transform, contour-integration

Do we have a closed form of this seemingly very simple inverse transformation?

If no closed form, what about its asymptotic form?

Does this satisfies the criterion to have its inverse transformation?

Comment: Since $\lim\limits_{s\to+\infty}\dfrac{1}{\arctan s}=\dfrac{2}{\pi}$ , its inverse Laplace transform should be $\dfrac{2\delta(t)}{\pi}$ adding with something.